# Android TV: getting last used apps through UsageStatsManager

Tags: android, android-tv, usagestatsmanager

I'm writing an app to track which apps have recently been used on Android TV. I've already written it for regular Android phones an it's working fine. However, when I bring the code to Android TV, it's not working. Things I have done.

1. Declare this in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
   tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
   ```
2. Check if I don't have permission to usage access, bring up setting

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Use **UsageStatsManager** to query last used package names

   ```
   List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, currentTime - 1000 * 10, currentTime);
   ```

However, my app fails right at the point where it needs to bring up the *Usage Access activity*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.kantarmedia.tvcomp.kantartvcompanion, PID: 7727
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kantarmedia.tvcomp.kantartvcompanion/com.kantarmedia.tvcomp.kantartvcompanion.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS }
```

Seems like Android TV doesn't allow this feature (this is from the Android TV Emulator). So, without this permission, the **UsageStatsManager** always returns an empty string.

Does anyone know how to fix this or if there's another way to achieve this task?

My goal is to track which app is currently on the foreground on an Android TV (again it's already working for Android phones). Think of it like an app to research the popularity of apps by measuring the time the user spends on each app.

Comment: When I searched like this app in store on Android TV . Can't found anything, then decide to develop simple for myself, but then I read your question.
Please, let me know, have you already solved this question? I want to track daily how many we watching in tv.

Comment: I'm building [ActivityWatch](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/), an open source cross-platform time tracking application. We've just recently started exploring Android support and are interested in getting this to work for Android TV but disappointed to see this might not be possible. Anyway, we're tracking this in an issue [here](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-android/issues/5) for anyone who might be passing by.